# type of data structure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

```
static String words[][] = {{" banana "," bob "},
                           {" ich "," du "},
                           {" are "," is "},
                           {" not"," yes "}};

static String quotes[]= {"i want to eat",
                         "can I help you?",
                         "Please, send a message",};
```

What type of data structure it is and how can I use it?

Answer (score 3):

Both `words` and `quotes` are *arrays*.

`words` is an array of arrays of strings, and `quotes` is an array of `String`s.

You can "use" `words` by doing something like

```
System.out.println(words[0][1]); // prints " bob "
```

and you can use `quotes` like

```
System.out.println(quotes[1]);   // prints "can I help you?"
```

**Further reading:**

- [Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

These are called *arrays*. If you don't know what those are, you should read an introductory book about programming (in Java), rather than asking questions here. You may also read the [Java tutorial about basics of the language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a 2D array and second one is 1D array of strings.

just google how to use 1D,2D,3D .... etc arrays in java.
The link below may help
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1162
Please make sure you post a question only after you do all the efforts due on your part.
cheers